# Django + wsgi = Forbidden 403

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

So 403 error is here.
My 000-default.conf from /etc/apache2/sites-available/:

```
<VirtualHost talkrecorder.ru:80>
ServerName talkrecorder.ru
ServerAlias www.talkrecorder.ru
ServerAdmin mail@talkrecorder.ru
DocumentRoot /srv/www/sampleapp/
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/sampleapp/sampleapp/wsgi.py
<Directory /srv/www/sampleapp>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My wsgi.py from srv/sampleapp/sampleapp:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/sampleapp/sampleapp')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/sampleapp/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

settings.py here: http://pastebin.sabayon.org/pastie/16969

Comment: What are your permissions?

Comment: Can you show your settings.py as well?

Comment: settings.py here http://pastebin.sabayon.org/pastie/16969 i'm logging as root

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py, your allowed hosts are empty. You should complete as following :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.talkrecorder.ru', 'talkrecorder.ru'] #Or any other host that you need
```

Comment: now works: <Directory /srv/www/sampleapp>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>